# Draw Circuit For LaTeX Documents: GUI

Tags: circuitikz

Currently, I use Circuitikz to draw my circuits for my LaTeX documents.  My issue is, it really takes a while to draw them and a GUI which would allow me to drag and drop the components would really be so much easier for this kind of thing.  Can anyone suggest to me suggest a GUI?  I also have other issues with Circuitikz that really make me want to find a better option...  Diodes are too big, I have to give coordinates to everything (so I can't really say, put R1 left of C1), and certain things are just a pain to do.  A GUI really would be so much better...

I've looked at XCircuit, but that also seems to have some issues and I failed at getting latex mode to work...

Comment: You could try https://github.com/ckuhlmann/lt2circuitikz